# React Material UI Autocomplete, prevent OnInputChange, after selecting value from dropdown

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I prevent React Material UI to not trigger onInputChange, when a person selects a option from the dropdown? After using the dropdown, it retriggers the API again, which I am trying to prevent .

```
    <Autocomplete
      options={patientOptions}
      onChange={(_event, newValue) => {
        onPatientChange(newValue);
      }}
      noOptionsText={
        <Typography>
          <Box color="text.hint">
            {patientLength === 0
              ? 'Type at least 1 character to search'
              : 'No results found.'}
          </Box>
        </Typography>
      }
      onInputChange={async (
        event: object,
        value: string,
        reason: string,
      ) => {
        setPatientLength(value.length);
        if (value.length > 0) {
          await getPatient(value, undefined).then(x => {
            setPatientOptions(x.patients);
          });
        }
      }}
      getOptionLabel={option => getPatientLabel(option)}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          value={patientValue}
          {...params}
        />
      )}
    />
```

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing the problem.

Comment: You add logic to `onInputChange` that checks whether the selected `value` is already present in `patientOptions` and if it is then do not `await getPatient`. Something like `if (!patientOptions.find(value))` then call your API, otherwise do not because a user selected an option from the dropdown instead of entering custom input. Or simply do not call the API if `reason === "reset"`.

Comment: beside add the condition for reason, You can make debounce to prevent massive number of request when input change quickly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent making API calls when a user selects an option from the dropdown, you can consult the `reason` argument to `onInputChange`. The `reason` will always be `reset` when a user selects an option and `input` when a user enters custom text. In the latter case you should also check whether the custom text is included in the `patientOptions`.

I've added the following conditions to to your conditional logic inside `onInputChange`: `reason === 'input' && !patientOptions.find(value)`.

```js
    <Autocomplete
      options={patientOptions}
      onChange={(_event, newValue) => {
        onPatientChange(newValue);
      }}
      noOptionsText={
        <Typography>
          <Box color="text.hint">
            {patientLength === 0
              ? 'Type at least 1 character to search'
              : 'No results found.'}
          </Box>
        </Typography>
      }
      onInputChange={async (
        event: object,
        value: string,
        reason: string,
      ) => {
        setPatientLength(value.length);
        if (value.length > 0 && reason === 'input' && !patientOptions.find(value)) {
          await getPatient(value, undefined).then(x => {
            setPatientOptions(x.patients);
          });
        }
      }}
      getOptionLabel={option => getPatientLabel(option)}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          value={patientValue}
          {...params}
        />
      )}
    />
```